# Drupal: Taxonomy: Make vocabulary optional for a specific content-type

Tags: drupal, forms, taxonomy

I understand that I need to go down the path of hook_form_alter, however this doesn't appear to be getting me very far, initially:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
  drupal_set_message($form['form_id']['#value']);
  switch ($form['form_id']['#value']){
    case 'partner_node_form':
       $form['taxonomy'][1]['#required']=FALSE;
       break;
  }
}
```

DSM outputs `partner_node_form` and the code fires when I go to /node/add/partner, however it doesn't make the field optional, and it is still given a red asterisk.

If I submit the form, it fails, stating that the field is required, but now DSM outputs `admin_block_theme_form` instead, which is preventing my alter code from even running.

Obviously, I'm quite lost, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I knew that there was a solution to this ;). Found it today when I was working on something else.

Install [content_taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) module. Once you do this you will have taxonomy as a CCK field in all the content types. Hence you can make it optional for a selected content type. You have an option to select the vocabulary and moreover you can use this like any other CCK field.

Comment: Yes I thought I might have to go down this route. I'm already using Hierarchical Select and Taxonomy Super Select on this project, I'm reluctant to add another Taxonomy Module, but I'll give it a go thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
define('MY_VOCABULARY', 1);

$form['taxonomy'][MY_VOCABULARY]['#required'] = 0;
```

it's works fine in drupal 6. what drupal version you use ?